# Twig - Why can't I access a variable I've set?

Tags: symfony, variables, twig

For some reason, a variable I'm setting in one form template bloc is not available in a child form block.

I have an 'entity' field type to present a selection of checkboxes to allow the user to select related items...

```
$builder
    ->add( 'title' )
    ->add(
        'apps',
        'entity',
        [
            'class'    => 'OurAdminBundle:App',
            'choices'  => $apps,
            'property' => 'title',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ]
    )
```

And here's the template that renders the form

```
// Effectively imported using the MopaBootstrapBundle
// {% form_theme form 'OurAdminBundle:Form:fields.html.twig %}

// Further in page theming
{% form_theme form _self %}

// Set variable when on the apps field, so it should be available to all child
// forms
{% block _gallery_apps_widget %}
    {% set custom_checkboxes = 1 %}
    {{ block('choice_widget') }}
{% endblock %}

// Attempt to retrieve the variable on the checkboxes within the apps entity 
/ field
{% block checkbox_widget %}
    {{ dump(custom_checkboxes|default(0) }}   // Displays 0
{% endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Here's the code from the fields.html.twig file (with minor debugging additions...

```
{% block choice_widget_expanded %}
    {{ dump(custom_checkboxes|default(0)) }}
    {% set custom_checkboxes = custom_checkboxes|default(0) %}
    {{ dump(custom_checkboxes|default(0)) }}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default(''))}) %}
    {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class ~ ' ' ~ (widget_type != '' ? (multiple ? 'checkbox' : 'radio') ~ '-' ~ widget_type : ''))}) %}
    {% if expanded %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default(horizontal_input_wrapper_class)}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {% if widget_type != 'inline' %}
        <div class="{{ multiple ? 'checkbox' : 'radio' }}">
        {% endif %}
            <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
                {{ form_widget(child, {'horizontal_label_class': horizontal_label_class, 'horizontal_input_wrapper_class': horizontal_input_wrapper_class, 'attr': {'class': attr.widget_class|default('')}}) }}
                {{ child.vars.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
            </label>
        {% if widget_type != 'inline' %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_expanded %}
```

... which successfully displays '1' on both counts.

I've racked my brains over this one, but can't for the life of me understand why I can't access the variable in the checkbox_widget block.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how Symfony renders form fields when calling `form_widget()` or any other `form*` family of functions.

Symfony creates a new separate scope which do not share the scope of the parent (in order to prevent scope polluting while rendering fields).

If you which to pass a variable to the checkbox widget, edit the `form_widget` call in the `choice_widget_expanded` to pass on the `custom_checkboxes` as so (added tabbing for clarity only):

```
{{ form_widget(child, {
    'horizontal_label_class': horizontal_label_class,
    'horizontal_input_wrapper_class': horizontal_input_wrapper_class,
    'attr': {'class': attr.widget_class|default('')},
    'custom_checkboxes': custom_checkboxes
}) }}
```